# Not Connected to server(Openfire) using asmack api in android project

Tags: java, android, xml, xmpp, asmack

I have a simple code which will show "Available" and "Unavailable" using asmack api, but whenever i click on the button it throws a message of not being connected to server. I am posting my code below.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.usingxmpp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.usingxmpp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/string_head" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button1"
        android:onClick="onClick1"
        />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button2"
        android:onClick="onClick2"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Usingxmpp</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="string_head">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="button1">Avail</string>
    <string name="button2">Unavail</string>



</resources>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.usingxmpp;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ConnectionConfiguration connfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("acer-PC",5222,"acer-pc");
    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connfig);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try
        {

            connection.connect();
                    connection.login("rahul","rahul");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public void onClick1(View v)
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {

                try
                {   


                    Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                    presence.setStatus("I am available");
                    connection.sendPacket(presence);
                    //String status = presence.getStatus();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You are Available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        ).start();

    }

    public void onClick2(View v)
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {   
                    Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.unavailable);
                    presence.setStatus("I am unavailable");
                    connection.sendPacket(presence);
                    //String status = presence.getStatus();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "UnAvailable now!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        ).start();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Logcat

```
12-02 14:41:40.809: W/System.err(5464): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server.
12-02 14:41:40.839: W/System.err(5464):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:194)
12-02 14:41:40.839: W/System.err(5464):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:355)
12-02 14:41:40.839: W/System.err(5464):     at com.example.usingxmpp.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:44)
12-02 14:41:40.839: W/System.err(5464):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

When I press Avail button the above errors comes in logcat.
Please help me in solving this problem of connecting to server.
Thanks
(Note: Runnning this project on my device)

Comment: hi i am getting same error, did you find any way out

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this code sequence:

```
connection.login("rahul","rahul");
connection.connect();
```

You need to be connected *before* you can login. Sounds reasonable, does it? Therefore you need to change the code to:

```
connection.connect();
connection.login("rahul","rahul");
```

Comment: Hey @Flow I have changed the code as you mentioned but still the same problem exist, as mentioned in the logcat file

Comment: Then I suggest debugging to find out why connect() does not connect :)

Comment: Hey @Flow still the same! Can you find any alternative to the code or something? PLease

Answer (score 0):

It could be because your android xmpp client is not able to connect to your host (in your case acer-PC). I mentioned the IP address for host on which the xmpp server is installed and it worked for me. You have to be careful with IP address, you may directly use your local WIFI IP address, you will be able to connect to xmpp server from android device if both your PC & android device are using the same WIFI. In case if you are using External IP address you may have to do some additional configurations as discussed here in this [link](http://im-a-developer-too.blogspot.ca/2014/04/creating-android-xmpp-client-using.html)